# What is the difference between SSCLI 2.0 (ROTOR) and .NET?

Tags: .net, comparison, sscli, rotor

Is there a large difference between the SSCLI 2.0 and .NET, I know that Microsoft wouldn't release their garbage collector or JIT compiler and simpler implementations are used, but as far as the rest is concerned is there much difference?

Comment: Do you know they wouldn't release their GC/JIT implementation? I think it's less likely that they would spend extra time to write another implementation just to release it as source.

Comment: I had a look at the source, the SSCLI GC is only 2 generation not 3 gen like the .net, also the JIT compiler looks too friendly for the 'real' thing.

Comment: .NET 3 uses the same runtime engine as .NET 2 (it's just frameworks changes). .NET 4 will be the first version since 2 to ship with a different runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a [link](http://www.ics.heacademy.ac.uk/events/presentations/47_Advanced%20Computer%20Science%20-%20Teaching%20with%20the%20SSCLI.ppt) for a comparison. pritty much sums it up..

Comment: The provided link is broken

Answer (score 1):

SSCLI is not licensed to be used in production. It's intended for educational use / peer review type things.

Comment: although that is true, not really what i was after, more towards the functionality side.

Comment: SSCLI can be considered as a .NET prototype. So it has well too many differences from .NET.

If you are really looking for the words Paul mentioned, you should be able to read the license file along with SSCLI source code. 

If I were you, I rather spend time on Mono, which is a better implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in GC and JIT. they simpfied these two feature when deploy to SSCLI.